# How to stitch png files with OpenCV correctly (without the "black region")?

Tags: python, opencv, png, image-stitching

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img_1 = cv2.imread('right.png')
```

https://pasteboard.co/J5cdLV0.png

```
img_2 = cv2.imread('left.png')
```

https://pasteboard.co/J5cdrBK.png

```
img1 = cv2.cvtColor(img_1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img_2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2,None)

bf = cv2.BFMatcher()

matches = bf.knnMatch(des1,des2, k=2)

good = []
for m in matches:
    if (m[0].distance < 0.5*m[1].distance):
        good.append(m)
matches = np.asarray(good)


if (len(matches[:,0]) >= 4):
    src = np.float32([ kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in matches[:,0] ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
    dst = np.float32([ kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in matches[:,0] ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
    H, masked = cv2.findHomography(src, dst, cv2.RANSAC, 5.0)
else:
    raise AssertionError('Can’t find enough keypoints.')
    
dst = cv2.warpPerspective(img_1,H,((img_1.shape[1] + img_2.shape[1]), img_1.shape[0]+img_2.shape[0])) #wraped image
dst[0:img_2.shape[0], 0:img_2.shape[1]] = img_2 #stitched image
cv2.imwrite('result.png',dst)
plt.imshow(dst)
plt.show()
```

The result is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q10va.jpg

What do I have to change in the code, to stitch the images correctly (show the right part of the image, instead of the "black block")?

Comment: The input images you posted are JPG not PNG. So if you had transparency  on the left image, that will show as black. That may be where your black areas are showing. The left JPG file shows a white region on the right side of the shape you are seeing as black. I suspect you are losing transparency. Can you post the actual PNG files in a way that do not get changed to JPGs

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, I edited.
Left png file: https://pasteboard.co/J5cdrBK.png
Right png file: https://pasteboard.co/J5cdLV0.png

Comment: When you read an image in OpenCV, the default is to remove the alpha channel. You need to keep it. So use `cv2.imread(left.png, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)`

Comment: I tiredt it, now yes, it reads correctly the png file, but now I have problem with the shapes, in this row:

dst[0:img_1.shape[0], 0:img_1.shape[1]] = img_2 #stitched image

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1923,2160,4) into shape (1080,1920,3)

Comment: Add an opaque alpha channel to the right image so they have the same shape. You can do that with cv2.cvtColor(). See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#ga397ae87e1288a81d2363b61574eb8cab and cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#ga4e0972be5de079fed4e3a10e24ef5ef0

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different detector like `bf = cv2.ORB_create()` or `bf = cv2.BRISK_create()`.